# How to form a numpy matrix of known number of rows but unknown number of columns?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to form a feature matrix that consists of peaks that are obtained through Power Spectral Density (PSD). I have around 1425 data files where this number is going to be the number of rows for my matrix. However, the peaks vary from each file as each file might have a different number of peaks (Say, for example, file 15 has 5 peaks and file 20 has 3 peaks). Therefore, how can I formulate a matrix where it inputs the peaks with regards to the number of columns?

I tried to implement the code (which can be found below), however, I had to initialise the number of columns and it keeps on printing even though it passes the range of number of columns

```
Data_PSD = np.zeros((15, 1425))
# Forming a feature matrix from peaks PSD values:
y_axis_PSD_peaks = np.asarray(y_axis[0].transpose())
DataFrame_Feature_PSD = np.array(y_axis_PSD_peaks)
DataSizecolumnPSD = DataSizecolumnPSD + 1
# print('Data Size column: ', DataSizecolumn)
Data_PSD[DataSizecolumnPSD - 1] = DataFrame_Feature_PSD
if DataSizecolumnPSD in range(1, y_axis.shape[0]):
    DataSizerowPSD = DataSizerowPSD + 1
    # print('Data Size row: ', DataSizerow)
    Data_PSD[DataSizerowPSD - 1] = DataFrame_Feature_PSD
    if DataSizecolumnPSD == 0:
        Data_PSD[DataSizecolumnPSD - 1] = 0
print('Signal/Exp. {0}'.format(count))
# print('Data Frame: ', Data)
Data_tran = Data_PSD.transpose()
# print('Data Frame Transpose: ', Data_tran)
# PSD_Matrix = np.append(arr=PSD_Matrix, values=Data_tran)
Feature_PSD_Matrix = Data_tran
print('Saved PSD Dataset file', Feature_PSD_Matrix)
```

I keep on having error after reading file 16. The error is:
    IndexError: index 15 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15

**Update 1**

I tried to implement the list, however, I am getting errors like `[TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable]`. The code for the list can be found below:

```
y_axis_PSD_peaks = np.asarray(y_axis[0].transpose())
DataFrame_Feature_PSD = np.array(y_axis_PSD_peaks)
Data_PSD = DataFrame_Feature_PSD.tolist()
for row in Data_PSD:
    for elem in row:
        print(elem, end=' , ')
    Feature_PSD_Matrix = Data_PSD
```

I found this website: https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/#section_4

**Update 2**

I managed to solve the probelm by just doing the following code:

```
for row in range(1425):
    Data_PSD.append(PSD_Peaks_list[0:PSD_Peaks_list_shape[0]])
    row =+1
    print(Data_PSD)
    break
Feature_PSD_Matrix = Data_PSD
```

Now, I am currently trying to save the matrix into a txt file, however, it keeps on printing empty lines with the exact number of rows. How can I save a list of float numbers in the txt file? The following code is what I keep on getting empty lines:

```
    with open('filename.txt','w') as out_file:
    for i in range(len(Feature_PSD_Matrix)):
        out_string = ""
        # Feature_PSD_Matrix_str = map(str, Data_PSD)
        out_string = Data_PSD
        out_string = "\n"
        out_file.write('{} \n'.format(out_string))
```

**Update 3**

```
[[0.0007990594037643691, 0.0004403783323228196, 0.000598699480390045, 0.0007168056730554628], [0.0008817249681644274, 0.00045377012471994107, 0.0006534686195005596, 0.0008000537399756023], [0.0005702091244336749, 0.00037008247488756936, 0.0005395840488197647, 0.0005684589958136876]]
```

I want to change it to:

```
[[0.0007990594037643691, 0.0004403783323228196, 0.000598699480390045, 0.0007168056730554628]
[0.0008817249681644274, 0.00045377012471994107, 0.0006534686195005596, 0.0008000537399756023]
[0.0005702091244336749, 0.00037008247488756936, 0.0005395840488197647, 0.0005684589958136876]]
```

Comment: Just use python lists?

Comment: This is normal. For array of size 15, the indices are from 0 to 14 inclusive

Comment: @user2699 Can you elaborate with an example please?

Comment: @tstanisl well, I changed the part 'Data_PSD = np.zeros((15, 1425))'  to 'Data_PSD = np.zeros((1425, y_axis.shape[0])) ', however, the matrix always reach 129 rows not 1425 rows.  what could be my mistake?

Comment: Create a list i python. Now each element of this list could be a new list with different size

Comment: well, I am trying using the list but I am not sure about my code and I am having errors. See the updated post.

Comment: @Mojo ok, so what is your loop condition? How can you know a number of iterations?

Comment: @tstanisl number of iterations around 1425 and for the loop condition I want it print all the peaks that it can find from 'y_axis_PSD_peaks variable' and then move to next line and wait of the next.

Comment: It looks that Data_PSD is 1d array. It has no rows in it. It is a row. That is why inner tries to iterate over "rows" of a row which are scalar. Scalar are not iterables

Comment: You are confusing yourself with needless `asarray` and `transpose`.  Make sure you understand what dimensions (or length) each item has at each point in the code.  Don't guess.  Reason it out, and then test (with `print(obj.shape)` statements).  Test code sequences in an interactive Python session.

Comment: @hpaulj I managed to solve the problem thanks for the help.

Comment: @tstanisl I managed to solve the problem but now I am trying to save the list into a txt file. See the updated post

Comment: @Mojo, change some of "=" to "+=" while creating ```out_string``` and it should work :). Moreover you can convert Data_PSD to string with ```str(Data_PSD)```

Comment: @tstanisl Thanks, it worked! Well, the only thing is that it prints the whole list. Is there a way to split them? say, for example, see the updated post

Comment: @Mojo, interesting, ```str(Data_PSD)``` should produce string with newlines. Try to use ```np.array2string```. It has a lot of options for formatting

Comment: @tstanisl it worked like a charm!! I just had to reassign the list to numpy and then replace the str into np.array2string and then it works. In the txt file, it becomes like this [list([0.0007990594037643691, 0.0004403783323228196, 0.000598699480390045, 0.0007168056730554628]). But, ill just change it through 'find and replace' after I get the whole matrix. Thank you very much for your help.